# Cannot call getSupportFragmentManager() from activity

Tags: android, android-activity, android-fragments

I have an activity which has a fragment.

XML:

```
 <fragment android:name="com.example.androidcalculator.ResultFragment"
            android:id="@+id/result_fragment"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

And I want to call a method from ResultFragment from a method in the Activity, but getSupportFragmentManager "doesn't exist":

```
FragmentManager fragMan = getSupportFragmentManager();
```

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 195, accepted):

Your activity doesn't extend [FragmentActivity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity.html) from the support library, therefore the method is not present in the superclass

If you are targeting api 11 or above, you could use [Activity.getFragmentManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#getFragmentManager%28%29) instead.

Comment: `FragmentManager` is deprecated now.

Comment: Not completely true, you're supposed to use the AndroidX FragmentManager.

Comment: I am using ComponentActivity here not AppcompactActivity and in componentActivity getsupportManger() is giving error anyiIdea

Answer (score 62):

extend class to `AppCompatActivity` instead of `Activity`

Answer (score 20):

get current activity from parent, then using this code

```
getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()
```

Comment: can also try FragmentManager fragMan = getFragmentManager();

Answer (score 5):

You need to extend `FragmentActivity` instead of `Activity`

Answer (score 3):

Simply Use

```
 FragmentManager fm = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
```

Remember always when accessing fragment inflating in MainLayout use
Casting or `getActivity()`.

Answer (score 2):

import

```
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
```

Comment: Importing is not sufficient here - you have to inherit from `FragmentActivity` too.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me. Running android API 19 and above.

```
FragmentManager fragMan = getFragmentManager();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
getCurrentActivity().getFragmentManager()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
((FragmentActivity) activity).getSupportFragmentManager();
```

Comment: Thank you for your interest in contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This question already has quite a few answers—including one that has been extensively validated by the community. Are you certain your approach hasn’t been given previously? **If so, it would be useful to explain how your approach is different, under what circumstances your approach might be preferred, and/or why you think the previous answers aren’t sufficient.** Can you kindly [edit] your answer to offer an explanation?

Answer (score -1):

Instead of

```
extends Fragment
```

use

```
extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment
```

This works for me.
for *API14 and above

Answer (score -2):

I used `FragmentActivity`

```
TabAdapter = new TabPagerAdapter(((FragmentActivity) getActivity()).getSupportFragmentManager());
```