# Android - Dialog getSupportFragmentManager undefined

Tags: android, dialog, alert, android-dialogfragment

I'm trying to implement a simple Dialog into my code. But it does not work. I have searched every available tutorial, including the official developer guide but nothing works. The error I got from logcat is that I'm getting a nullPointerException, I'm guessing that's on the getActivity. Any help?

This is what I have: This is my Custom Dialog class.

```
public class SaveDialog extends DialogFragment {

    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        builder.setTitle("Save Password");
        builder.setView(getContentView());
        Dialog dialog = builder.create();
        dialog.show();
        return dialog;
    }

    private View getContentView() {
        LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
    
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog, null);
    }
}
```

and this is my main activity where the onclick occurs

```
private void savePassword() {
    SaveDialog savePasswordDialog = new SaveDialog();
    savePasswordDialog.show(savePasswordDialog.getSupportFragmentManager(), "tag");
}
```

Every single time I fire up the onClick, the app crashes. On top of that, currently I am trying to use getSupportFragmentManager, but it says it's undefined.

Comment: do not forget to share `Logcat` when app crashes.

Comment: I guess problem is in `getActivity()`. It is returning `null`

Comment: In Activity, you should use just getSupportFragmentManager(), cause it's the Activity's method.

Comment: Yes, the problem is that getActivity is returning null. I have tried to use Context and pass it from the Main activity but the problem persists.

Answer (score 14):

You should use getSupportFragmentManager(), which is only available in FragmentActivity.

You should change your activity to a fragment one.

Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13443811/cannot-call-getsupportfragmentmanager-from-activity)

Comment: How can i call getSupportFragmentManager() from the Fragment class (extends Fragment)?

Comment: getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager() if I recall correctly

Answer (score 7):

Try this..works!!

---

```
((AppCompatActivity)activity).getSupportFragmentManager()
```

Answer (score 1):

Just call getFragmentManager() from your android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment or android.support.v4.app.Fragment. It will return a android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager (this is, the support FragmentManager)

Answer (score -1):

You don't have to manually show the dialog in onCreateDialog(), just returning it is sufficient for DialogFragment to work its magic (and show the dialog) when you call savePassword().

So remove this line from onCreateDialog :
dialog.show();

and it should work. Good luck!