# How to remove ActionBarActivity?

Tags: android

I am successfully running the Activity, but I see the titlebar above the scrolltabs. I want the titlebar to be removed, when I try:

```
public class Iphone6Activity extends Activity
```

I get error Cannot resolve method 'getSupportFragmentManager()'

Below is my main Activity:

```
package com.hashmi.omar.vodafonestore;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;




public class Iphone6Activity extends ActionBarActivity {

// Declaring Your View and Variables

ViewPager pager;
ViewPagerAdapter_ip6 adapter;
SlidingTabLayout tabs;
CharSequence Titles[]={"Overview","Specifications", "Choose a Bundle"};
int Numboftabs =3;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_iphone6);




    // Creating The ViewPagerAdapter and Passing Fragment Manager, Titles for the Tabs and Number Of Tabs.
    adapter =  new ViewPagerAdapter_ip6(getSupportFragmentManager(),Titles,Numboftabs);

    // Assigning ViewPager View and setting the adapter
    pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.ip6pager);
    pager.setAdapter(adapter);

    // Assigning the Sliding Tab Layout View
    tabs = (SlidingTabLayout) findViewById(R.id.ip6tabs);


    // Setting the ViewPager for the SlidingTabsLayout
    tabs.setViewPager(pager);



     }



}
```

How can I remove actionbaractivity?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ActionBarActivity` is deprecated, so I suggest first change it to `AppCompatActivity`:

```
public class Iphone6Activity extends AppCompatActivity
```

and in your `styles.xml`

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
</style>
```

Comment: I tried this and it shows the following error:
Cannot resolve symbol 'AppCompatActivity'

Comment: Add `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'` to your bulld.gradle. Then sync and you will be able to import library `AppCompatActivity`.

Comment: Just tried your updated answer, it works!
Turns out that I just had to add the code into styles, I have left ActionBarActivity as it is (I know it's deprecated, but for my theme, it doesn't pose a problem)
Thanks so much!

Comment: Remember to mark problem as solved (tick at my post) =]

Answer (score 0):

inside your activity:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    this.getActionBar().setTitle("");

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

in your manifest:

```
 <activity
        android:name="your activity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
        android:label="Label of your Activity HERE"
        android:launchMode="singleTop">
       ...
```

choose one of them, in your manifest just set  android:label to a empty String (if you choose manifest way)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this question: [Cannot call getSupportFragmentManager() from activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13443811/cannot-call-getsupportfragmentmanager-from-activity)

Also, to remove title bar from your view, change the theme of your layout xml or your android manifest(this would change the theme of the entire application, you might have to use a toolbar if you want custom toolbars in activities) to something like Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar.

Lastly, ActionBarActivity extends Activity so you don't really need to change it.