# Cannot use getSupportFragmentManager() in RecyclerAdapter

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have a problem with my RecyclerViewAdapter. I want to show my fragments with TabLayout,CardView and ViewPager entegrations. I'm not using Activity, using Fragment. I have a Fragment. And this fragment contains Cardview. And this Cardview contains Tablayout and Viewpager.

How can I use getSupportFragmentManager() in this adapter or how can I edit this adapter? Here is my code:

**RecyclerViewAdapter.java**

```
public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends 
RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    public ArrayList<String> myValues;
    public RecyclerViewAdapter (ArrayList<String> myValues){
        this.myValues= myValues;
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View listItem = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.cardview_select_area, parent, false);
        return new MyViewHolder(listItem);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return myValues.size();
    } 

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
            private TextViewPoppins myTextView;
            private TabItem tab_loc,tab_area;
            private ViewPager viewPager;
            private TabLayout tabLayout;

            public MyViewHolder(View itemView)
            {
                super(itemView);
                myTextView = (TextViewPoppins)itemView.findViewById(R.id.select_area);
                tabLayout = (TabLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tabs);
                tab_loc= (TabItem) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tab_loc);
                tab_area= (TabItem) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tab_area);
                tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setIcon(R.drawable.ic_location_green));
                tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setIcon(R.drawable.ic_kort));
                viewPager = (ViewPager) itemView.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
                setupViewPager(viewPager);


            }
        }

    private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager)
    {

        ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new 
        ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()); 
        //this line gives the error.
        adapter.addFragment(new LocationFragment(), "ONE");
        adapter.addFragment(new AreaFragment(), "TWO");
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);


    }

    class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter
    {
        private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
        private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

        public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager)
        {
            super(manager);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position)
        {
            return mFragmentList.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mFragmentList.size();
        }

        public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title)
        {
            mFragmentList.add(fragment);
            mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I think you intended to do: ReyclerView -> Fragment -> Activity with TabLayout and ViewPager. This is how you accomplish that: first, the method where you set up your `ViewPager` and `TabLayout` ("setupViewPager") should be in an `Activity` which has the `getFragmentManger()` or `getSupportFragmentManager()` if you're using an `AppCompatActivity`. Your adapter class can be in another file, though.

Secondly, it also appears you're trying to put your `TabLayout` and `ViewPager` in your `ViewHolder`. ViewHolders are used in `RecyclerView` lists, not for lateral navigation. Take this code out of the class:

```
tabLayout = (TabLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tabs);
tab_loc= (TabItem) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tab_loc);
tab_area= (TabItem) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tab_area);
tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setIcon(R.drawable.ic_location_green));
tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setIcon(R.drawable.ic_kort));
viewPager = (ViewPager) itemView.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
setupViewPager(viewPager);
```

Finally, here is how it should look in your MainActivity under `onCreate`:

```
// Get the ViewPager and set it's PagerAdapter so that it can display items
ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
viewPager.setAdapter(new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));

// Give the TabLayout the ViewPager
TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
```

[Here](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Google-Play-Style-Tabs-using-TabLayout) is an additional link reference.

Comment: I'm not using Activity, using Fragment. I have a Fragment. And this fragment contains cardview. And this cardview contains tablayout and viewpager. Is this order right? I mean should I change something or what?

Comment: Your `Fragment` has to be in an `Activity` in order to function. Normally, a list of `CardView`s goes into a `Fragment` which is a part of an `Activity`. If you want a list of `CardView`s, this is the order that it should be in.

Comment: Why it has to be an Activity? Can't I show a fragment in a fragment?

Comment: @YunusHaznedar You can, but it's best practice to not do so. There always has to be a root `Activity` as defined in your Android manifest file for the system to launch your app. [Here's](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html) some more information.

Comment: I called them different place, as you told. And it worked. Thanks, good sir!

Comment: You are very welcome. I wish you the best in your Android app endeavors.

Comment: Thanks, btw ysorry for late feedback.  Have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

Move the ViewPagerAdapter class in MainActivity.java and setup the ViewPager in the onCreate() method in MainActivity.java.
getSupportFragmentManager() will work only if your class extends Activity.
Have a look at this :
[Cannot call getSupportFragmentManager() from activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13443811/cannot-call-getsupportfragmentmanager-from-activity)

Comment: I'm using Fragment not Activity. Don't we have an another solutions?

Comment: Use getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager() in the fragment which contains this RecyclerView. Setup your ViewPager in that fragment.

Answer (score 0):

Try `setupViewPager(viewPager);` inside `onBindViewHolder`, I think that should solve your issue.

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
setupViewPager(holder.viewPager);
}
```

Comment: Sir, I'm having a problem using getSupportFragmentManager. Please give more detail.

Comment: I mean I don't get a error that "setupViewPager(holder.viewPager)" line

Comment: Oops, my bad. Thought you were having issue over there, Did you tried using ViewPagerAdapter(getActivity.getSupportFragmentManager()); 
Just a thought.

Comment: Sir, it's is not Activity. It's adapter.

Comment: Your adapter is called from activity or Fragment? also do you pass any Context?

Comment: Pass context like 
public RecyclerViewAdapter (ArrayList<String> myValues,Context mContext){
        this.myValues= myValues;
this.context = mContext;
    }
and use this as ViewPagerAdapter(mContext.getSupportFragmentManager());