# Which Fragment Manager is needed for TimePickerDialogue Fragment kotlin

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, dialog, datetimepicker

I am trying to implement a simple TimePickerDialogue fragment, which displays when a button in pressed in a layout which is also a fragment. The Android developer guide shows this in Java:

```
public void showTimePickerDialog(View v) {
    DialogFragment newFragment = new TimePickerFragment();
    newFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "timePicker");
}
```

and says:

> The show() method requires an instance of FragmentManager and a unique name for the fragment.

When I converted this to Kotlin there is no `getSupportFragmentManager` method offered. What should I use instead?

```
class AlertsFragment : Fragment() {    

    fun showTimePickerDialog(v: View) {
        val newFragment = TimePickerFragment()
        newFragment.show(FragmentManager(), "timePicker") // WHAT FRAGMENTMGR???
    }
}
```

I am importing `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`

My MainActivity will display the TimePickerDialogue fragment as well as the Fragment that has a button to open the TimePickerDialogue. MainActivity has a tablayout using fragments. 
Does anything need to be changed in MainActivity to make the TimePickerDialogue show() function work in the AlertsFragment?

```
class MainActivity : FragmentActivity(){

    private lateinit var pagerAdapter: TabPagerAdapter

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        pagerAdapter = TabPagerAdapter(supportFragmentManager)
        pagerAdapter.addFragments(WorkoutGridFragment(), "Workouts")
        pagerAdapter.addFragments(AlertsFragment(), "Reminders")
        pagerAdapter.addFragments(AboutFragment(), "About")

        // customViewPager is the viewpager created in the activity_main xml layout
        customViewPager.adapter = pagerAdapter

        // set up the viewpager with the tablayout
        customTabLayout.setupWithViewPager(customViewPager)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fragments don't have a SupportFragmentManager field or getter. This applies whether you write it in Kotlin or Java.

Activities, however, do. So call the activity and get the supportFragmentManager:

```
fun showTimePickerDialog(v: View) {
    val newFragment = TimePickerFragment()
    newFragment.show(activity.supportFragmentManager, "timePicker") 
}
```

Also, if [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/pickers) is what you were reading in the docs, you'll see this:

> Also make sure that **your activity** that displays the time picker extends **FragmentActivity instead of the standard Activity class**. (emphasis mine)

Which implies the `showTimePickerDialog` method is defined in an Activity. And don't get this wrong, I'm not saying you have to define it in an activity, but since that's what they do in the docs, they can call the SupportFragmentManager directly. But if you call it from a fragment or anywhere outside an activity, you need an activity instance.

Comment: thanks Zoe, when I add activity. the red error line moves to show. My MainActivity displays the timePicker and the Fragment, and I have it extending AppCompatActivity. The showTimePickerDialog is added in the fragment XML file as an onclick attribute on a button. Do I have to define the button in the fragment instead?

Comment: I can't reproduce with `val x: DialogFragment; x.show()` (would obviously not run, but it doesn't show up as an error). Does `TimePIckerFragment` actually extend `DialogFragment`?

Comment: class TimePickerFragment : DialogFragment(), TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener {

Comment: Still can't reproduce. You might need to invalidate caches and restart, but `show` works fine for me

Comment: in MainActivity which holds the fragment do I have to declare the supportFragmentManager somehow?

Comment: Your activity needs to extend FragmentActivity or AppCompatActivity. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/13443811/6296561