# Using Custom Diaglogs in a recycler view

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-dialogfragment

I am attempting to have it so when a user taps on a post a custom dialog pops up asking if the user is sure they would like to advance to the next screen

I am following [CodingInFlows](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ARezg1D9Zd0) Video on how to implement this

The issue I am dealing with is in my recycler adapter I am unable to use the `getSupportFragmentManager` (8:24 in the video) after playing around I think that the issue is according to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13443811/cannot-call-getsupportfragmentmanager-from-activity) that I am not extending fragment manager but I don't see how I am able to do that since it is a recycler adapter

adapter

```
        @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ViewHolder holder, int position) {

...

        holder.parentLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                openDialog();


//old code to open acitity
                int pos = holder.getAdapterPosition();
                Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, Confirmation_Activity.class);
                intent.putExtra("Message_ID", blog_list.get(pos).getMessage_doc());
                mContext.startActivity(intent);

            }
        });

    }

    public void openDialog(){
        Confirmation_Dialog confirmation_dialog = new Confirmation_Dialog();
        confirmation_dialog.show();
    }
```

Dialog

```
    public class Confirmation_Dialog extends AppCompatDialogFragment {

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

        LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_dialog, null);

        builder.setView(view)
                .setTitle("Are You Sure")
                .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

                    }
                })
                .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

                    }
                });
        return builder.create();

    }
}
```

How should I go about solving this problem any feedback is great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by using

```
fragmentManager manager = ((AppCompatActivity)mContext).getSupportFragmentManager();
```

and the passing it as

```
confirmation_dialog.show(manager, "example dialog");
```

hope this helps!