# How to use android.support.v4.app.Fragment with Activity class?

Tags: android, android-fragments

Ok here is the issue, the native Android Fragment is deprecated.
This will be use in an Unity Android native plugin.
In the old ways you simply create a Fragment class like this:

```
        public class UnityAndroidNativeplugin extends Fragment
        {
        public static void Init()
        { 
          instance = new UnityAndroidNativePlugin
          UnityPlayer.currentActivity.
          getFragmentManager().
          beginTransaction().add(instance, UnityAndroidNativeplugin.LOG_TAG).commit();
        }
        }
```

That works fine but I still don't get, if this is deprecated we should use the support fragment library. Ok I will update this.
So when I change to the new version it should be something like this.

```
    public class UnityAndroidNativeplugin extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment
    {
    public static void Init()
    { 
      instance = new UnityAndroidNativePlugin
      FragmentManager fragMan = UnityPlayer.currentActivity.getSupportFragmentManager();
      //This Fails
    }
    }
```

I already know that my main Activity should be a FragmentActivity.
[Cannot call getSupportFragmentManager() from activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13443811/cannot-call-getsupportfragmentmanager-from-activity) Check here.

So it's not possible to use android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager while using Android Activity (android.app.Activity)?

One solution is to override the Unity Main activity but that could have problems when using other plugins. Or maybe using something else than a fragment.

Answer (score 0):

> So it's not possible to use android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager while using Android Activity (android.app.Activity)

Correct.

> if this is deprecated we should use the support fragment library

Or, better yet, the AndroidX one, as the Support Library one will become obsolete before long.

Comment: Do you know where I can information or examples of using AndroidX fragments ?

Comment: @OscarLeif: It is pretty much the same as the Support Library ones, just replacing `android.support.v4` with `androidx.fragment`. So, [here is the `Fragment` class](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/Fragment.html). You need to extend from [the equivalent version of `FragmentActivity`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/FragmentActivity.html).